# How to call multiple setProps in enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-props

I have the following test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

import ListAdapter from './ListAdapter'
import TweetCard from './TweetCard'


describe('<ListAdapter />', () => {
    let wrapper, props

    beforeEach(() => {
        props = {
            data: [{
                user: { profile_image_url: 'someimage.png', name: 'Some name' },
                created_at: 'Sat Feb 02 19:06:09 +0000 2019',
                text: 'Hello word'
            }],
        };
        wrapper = shallow(<ListAdapter  {...props} />);

    })

    it('renders without crashing', () => {
        expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('renders one link anchor element', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('button')).toHaveLength(1);
        expect(wrapper.find(TweetCard)).toHaveLength(0);
    });

    it('check anchor tag text when it gets data and than try to set props', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('button').at(0).text()).toEqual('You have 1 tweet.');
        var { data } = wrapper.instance().props
        data = [data].concat({
            user: { profile_image_url: 'someimage.png', name: 'Some name' },
            created_at: 'Sat Feb 02 19:06:09 +0000 2019',
            text: 'Hello word'
        })
        wrapper = wrapper.setProps({ data })
        expect(wrapper.find('button').at(0).text()).toEqual('You have 2 tweets.');
        expect(wrapper.instance().props.data).toHaveLength(2)


    // UPDATED TEST TO GET 3 TWEETS
data = wrapper.instance().props
        data = [data].concat({
            user: { profile_image_url: 'someimage.png', name: 'Some name' },
            created_at: 'Sat Feb 02 19:06:09 +0000 2019',
            text: 'Hello word'
        })
        wrapper = wrapper.setProps({ data })
        expect(wrapper.find('button').at(0).text()).toEqual('You have 3 tweets.');
        expect(wrapper.instance().props.data).toHaveLength(3)
    });

    it('check state initialization defaults', () => {
        // we have one props getting passed so it will be 1
        expect(wrapper.state('data_count')).toEqual(1);
    });

    it('test onClick event of button', () => {
        // Try to click and than we should have toggleFlag be true and data_count be 0
        wrapper.find('button').simulate('click')
        expect(wrapper.state('data_count')).toEqual(0);
        expect(wrapper.find(TweetCard)).toHaveLength(1);
        expect(wrapper.find('button')).toHaveLength(0);
    });

})
```

And, on test where it says : `check anchor tag text when it gets data and than try to set props` I want to add more props after adding the second one, but I tried the same way for third prop and it just simply doesnt affect! Enzyme sometime is really awesome sometime just doenst make it easy. I know setProps is a async call too.

Anything?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you know your problem then... you need to wait for `setProps` to finish if it's async.

Comment: [`setProps`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setProps.html) is not async. what happens to your test case? I've created simple test case where `wrapper.setProps` is updated with changed array data and everything works as expected.

Comment: @skyboyer I have updated that test case to get 3 props...please have a look, but it didnt work. Instead it says `You have 1 tweet`

Comment: I've just figured out you are referring to `wrapper.instance`. I use `wrapper.setProps()` and `wrapper.props()`. try use the same way(while I believe it should be the same)

Comment: @skyboyer, I have tried that as well, it gives undefined than!

Comment: Since we can't see your component, I would suggest if you have any kind of lifecycle methods causing the render not to update, that could be your problem. Replace `wrapper = wrapper.setProps(...)` with just `wrapper.setProps(...)` and try `wrapper.update()` to make sure the component is in correct state.

Answer (score 3):

Acually no need to reassing to `wrapper` again.

`wrapper.setProps({ data })` instead of `wrapper = wrapper.setProps({ data })`

You have written right but Your `data` is already array then you did `[data].concat` instead of `data.concat`. But I'm not sure that this is the issue.

Comment: I have updated that test case to get 3 props...please have a look, but it didnt work. Instead it says `You have 1 tweet`

Comment: `data = wrapper.instance().props` it gets props but not props.data you should change to `data = wrapper.instance().props.data`

Comment: Could you please console.log(wrapper.instance().props) or debug I want to see what shows

Comment: That is one more annoying thing, console.log sometimes doesnt work at all!

Comment: :)))) 

Do you use webstorm? u can debug easly

Comment: VSCode! :) is what I am using

Comment: It will be more easy to debug if you use WebStorm)))

Comment: If console.log doesn't work then your test isn't getting to it either due to a failed test or an issue with your logic.

Answer (score 3):

You can update the props multiple times using `setProps`, but you aren't setting the props correctly i.e you are not using the `concat` method correctly. Also you need not set the return value of `setProps`

```
it('check anchor tag text when it gets data and than try to set props', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('button').at(0).text()).toEqual('You have 1 tweet.');
    var { data } = wrapper.instance().props
    data = data.concat({
        user: { profile_image_url: 'someimage.png', name: 'Some name' },
        created_at: 'Sat Feb 02 19:06:09 +0000 2019',
        text: 'Hello word'
    }) // data here is now an array of objects
    wrapper.setProps({ data })
    expect(wrapper.find('button').at(0).text()).toEqual('You have 2 tweets.');
    expect(wrapper.instance().props.data).toHaveLength(2)

    data = wrapper.instance().props
    data = data.concat({
        user: { profile_image_url: 'someimage.png', name: 'Some name' },
        created_at: 'Sat Feb 02 19:06:09 +0000 2019',
        text: 'Hello word'
    })
    wrapper.setProps({ data })
    expect(wrapper.find('button').at(0).text()).toEqual('You have 3 tweets.');
    expect(wrapper.instance().props.data).toHaveLength(3)
});
```

Comment: @Maverick, does the above solution work for you. Could you please confirm